# Monitoring a tcp port using Zenoss

Tags: monitoring, network-monitoring, zenoss

it's possible to monitor a general purpose service, listening on port 5896, i.e.: `tcp://production.enterprise.com:5896`

I just want know if this service is alive or offline, like a fast "`nc -zv <host> <port>`" command.

Regards,

And Past

Comment: I am not sure on what exactly you want to achieve. But if you are talking about a tool faster than nc to check remote port then I think any command will give you same or worse result than `nc`.

Comment: I just need to check if a port is open or closed using the Zenoss monitoring tool. (www.zenoss.org)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the zenoss IP service monitoring.  It basically uses SNMP to execute a telnet to the the port specified and send the response back over SNMP.